# How can we resolve a Jedis connection pool frequently occurring in production

Tags: redis, jboss, connection-pooling, jedis

Over the past several weeks, a Redis/Jedis error has suddenly started plaguing our production JBoss application.  We see a stack trace similar to the following very often:

```
2023-12-18 15:02:02,911 ERROR [com.our.own.JedisCacheWrapper] (default task-10186) Error while getting keys [cache : some_cache]: Exception: Error encountered while retrieveKeys operation [ cache : some_cache]
at
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_282]
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisExhaustedPoolException: Could not get a resource since the pool is exhausted
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53) [jedis-2.10.2.jar:]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:235) [jedis-2.10.2.jar:]
... 130 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unable to validate object
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:494) [commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361) [commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50) [jedis-2.10.2.jar:]
```

We are accessing Jedis through an obfuscation layer, but here are the salient connection pool settings:

- max idle connections = 10
- max active connections = 300
- max wait time for connection = 10s
- max heap size = 400MB

Note that in lower environments, we are unable to reproduce this stack trace.

Has anyone experienced a similar connection pool issue when using Jedis/Redis?